# Using two types of measurements with a div (only css?)

Tags: css, html

I have a div that I need to take up 100% of the page except for `x` amount of pixels.  I can't use JavaScript, is this possible?

I can set height like so:

```
height:100%;
```

or I could set it as:

```
height:0px;
```

But how do I make it a hundred percent subtract `x` pixels?

**EDIT**

This is why I need to do this:
[image]

You'll notice that the footer is being underlapped by the div.  Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: You can't in pure CSS. I really wish this was possible, though.

Comment: @Shaz +1 might as well have been the answer

Comment: CSS doesn't support math operations, period. Your choices for such things are Javascript, or doing the calculations on the server while generating the page.

Comment: Setting `height:100%` tends to be problematic as it usually takes 100% of the window height on load, which is what you're seeing now. If you are just trying to get the footer below the floated content, set a `clear` in css.

Comment: @Paul Sham, could you explain what a `clear` is?  I've never heard of it and I can't find anything about it on Google (I keep getting results for a clear property).  Thanks if you can :)

Comment: I was assuming on what you were trying to accomplish (that you wanted the footer to appear below all of the text, as in having to scroll to the bottom to see it) and that the text had been floated.

But, `clear` is used in conjunction with the css property `float`. Floating removes the element from the flow of elements and sticks it right or left. `clear: left`, `clear:right`, `clear:both` are just the methods for making sure elements "clear" these floated elements. If you set an element to `clear:left`, it will end up below floated elements and make it the only element on the left side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hGbX7/)**

Using `position: absolute;` you can!

Comment: LIFE SAVER!  I never even thought of that (I feel kind of dumb now!)

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done with native CSS. You'll need to either use two divs, or padding:

```
<div style="height:100%; position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 5px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

**OR:**

```
<div style="height:100%; padding-bottom: 5px;">
</div>
```

(I also wish CSS supported more complex math, variables, etc.)